# Enumeration of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, map, indexing, nested-function

My problem is consisting of following:
I have a nested list of following form:

```
{{B, v ** v, b ** B}, {b, B ** b}, {b ** B, v ** v}, {}}
```

And I want to enumerate every entity in the list in the following way:

```
{{Subscript[B, 1],Subscript[v, 2]**Subscript[v, 3],Subscript[b, 4]**Subscript[B, 5]},{Subscript[b, 6],Subscript[B, 7]**Subscript[b, 8]},{Subscript[b, 9]**Subscript[B, 10],Subscript[v, 11]**Subscript[v, 12]},{}}
```

I know how to do it using procedural style of programming so my question is this a way to do it in a purely functional way? During my attempts I find function MapIndexed, however all I have accomplished is following:

```
MapIndexed[Subscript[#1, #2] &, list, {-1}]
```

and result of execution of the command:

```
{{Subscript[B, {1,1}],Subscript[v, {1,2,1}]**Subscript[v, {1,2,2}],Subscript[b, {1,3,1}]**Subscript[B, {1,3,2}]},{Subscript[b, {2,1}],Subscript[B, {2,2,1}]**Subscript[b, {2,2,2}]},{Subscript[b, {3,1,1}]**Subscript[B, {3,1,2}],Subscript[v, {3,2,1}]**Subscript[v, {3,2,2}]},{}}
```

Is there is a way for somehow modify this command and obtain desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Module[{i = 1}, Replace[ expr, s_ :> Subscript[s, i++], {-1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

start = {{B, v ** v, b ** B}, {b, B ** b}, {b ** B, v ** v}, {}};

n = 1;
end = start /. 
  x_?(MemberQ[Variables[Level[start, {-1}]], #] &) :> Subscript[x, n++]
```

[image]